# How to secure send any hyperlink in mail body?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send hyperlink in mail body.

```
$invoice_link = $this->base_url.'/cityadmin/new_invoice_detail/5/'.$invoice_number;
$msg = "<p>Here is the <a href='".$invoice_link."'>link</a> please click to open direct invoice</p>";
```

When I send any email then link is going in email body working fine but it is creating simple link after open this link anyone can edit url simply.
But I want secure or encryptred link which no one can edit easily or understand.

How to make such type of link in email body ?

Comment: Then how would the intended user decrypt the link????

Comment: You can't simply secure that link, max you can go for `form` instead.

Comment: All you can do is amend the script that shows the linked invoice to check that the intended user is logged in and not anybody else

Comment: I think he means obtuse the URL so it's not easily guessable (and so people can't change the invoice number to view other orders). For that I'd recommend switching out `new_invoice_detail/5/'.$invoice_number;` for a random string. (or mayeb a cobination of 2?) I.e the final product will look like `new_invoice_detail/5/dfs342uy18dsh1/12318dfsg`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to avoid or at least to make it more difficult that someone can enter your invoice number that easily you might try the encryption library from Codeigniter

take a look [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html)

After correct Configuration you can try something like the following:

```
$this->load->library('encryption');

$invoice_link = $this->base_url.'/cityadmin/new_invoice_detail/5/'.bin2hex($this->encryption->encrypt($invoice_number));
`$msg = "<p>Here is the <a href='".$invoice_link."'>link</a> please click to open direct invoice</p>";
```

and in your controller function `new_invoice_detail` you simply decrypt it like

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
$invoice_number = $this->encryption->decrypt(pack('H*', $invoice_number));
```

> Don't forget to set your encryption key !

Comment: i am usin old version ci 1.7.2

Comment: i don't have to remind you, using this version is a tremendous risk, do i? But does that matter ? according to http://lang-lang.org/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html, it looks like 1.7.2 already had such a library isn't it ?